# undefined method `order' for nil:NilClass on chained where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

This is THE STUPIDEST thing (or I'm just stupid) but I'm getting a no method error for 'order' when my chained 'where' method returns no results.

Shouldn't this just return an empty array for @companies so that I can deal with that in my view?

Controller:

```
@companies = Company.all.filter(domicile = params[:domicile], due_date = params[:due_date]).order("name ASC")
```

Model:

```
def self.filter(domicile, due_date)
  where( "domicile_id = ?", domicile ) if domicile.present?
  where("extract(month from due_date) = ?", due_date) if due_date.present?
  end
```

views/companies/index:

```
@companies.each do |c|
   = c.name
- if @companies.empty?
  %p No companies were found.
```

Comment: Can you show us your error log in text?

Comment: instead of creating filter as method you should create `scope` filter, if you need to chain it.